# What would be the inverse function for the following condition?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions, inverse

[image]

I tried the problem but i couldn't take above condition in question in terms of f(x)

Comment: Are you sure this is related to *Mathematica* ?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by george2079 the equation can be solved by substition:

```
Reverse@Simplify[f[x] == 2 x + 1/x - f[1/x]/2 /. f[1/x] -> 2/x + x - f[x]/2]
```

> ```
> f[x] == 2 x
> ```

To find $f^{-1}(4)$ you can use

```
f = 2 # &;
InverseFunction[f][4]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Comment: readily derived.. `f[x]==2x+1/x-f[1/x]/2`, so `f[1/x]==2/x+x-f[x]/2`. Back substituting yields `f[x]==2x+1/x-(2/x+x-f[x]/2)/2`, which can be solved to yield `f[x]==2x`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a guess I could provide a reasonable explanation (when lacking it usually leads astray) thus we are prompting another way offering also understanding.

Since the given equation is a functional one and *Mathematica* does not offer a direct  functionality we have to  deduce with the system an adequate scheme for solving such  equations. Let's demonstrate it with `Solve`:

1. we are solving  related algebraic equations symbolically substituting appropriate function values with symbolic constants ( `{ f[x] == a, f[1/x] == b]}`)
2. then we solve `f[x] == 4`

So we have to solve this system using a simple trick:

$$2f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x}) =4x+\frac{2}{x}   $$and

$$2f(\frac{1}{x})+f(x) =\frac{4}{x}+2x  $$

```
{ f[x] == a, f[1/x] == b} /. Solve[ 2 a + b == 4 x + 2/x && 2 b + a == 4/x + 2 x, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{f[x] == 2 x, f[1/x] == 2/x}}
> ```

now we have

```
Solve[ 2 x == 4, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 2}}
> ```